# Generate keys in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, ant, keystore, key-generator

Currently I'm using ant XML to generate keys and sign jars.

I would like to eliminate the XML in the future by converting everything into a Gradle task without using ant.importBuild and not having to manually create keys with keytool -genkey. I believe I have the signing part figured out but need help with the key generation in gradle.

In the ant XML it currently looks like this:

```
<genkey alias="${key.alias}" keystore="${keystore.location}" storepass="${keystore.password}" dname="CN=name, OU=IT, O=org, C=US"/>
```

Is there an equivalent task to generate keys built into gradle? Unless I'm missing something Gradle seems to always assume the keys have already been generated.

I've read these [ant](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) and [signing plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html) pages but perhaps I can't see the forest because I'm lost in the trees.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle treats Ant as a 'First Class Citizen'.

You can invoke any common Ant task in Gradle simply by prefixing the task name with ant. Properties are set similar to parameters to a method call. For more information see this link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html

So, for your case it would look something like:

```
ant.genkey(alias:$keyAlias, keystore:$keystoreLocation, storepass:$storePass, dname:'$dName)
```

Comment: Wow, that is embarrassingly simple. Thank you! Follow up question. If I end up keeping the xml around for a little while, after ant.importBuild how could I reference for example key.alias property if antbuild.xml has <property name="key.alias" value="keyaliasvalue"/> ?  Can I simply do ant.key.alias at that point?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your secondary question. Easier with a concrete example.

build.xml:

```
<project name="TestProject" default="test" basedir=".">
  <property name="key.alias" value="keyaliasvalue"/>

  <target name="testtarget">
      <echo>Test Target</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

build.gradle:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

task test << {
    println("Value of ants key.alias property: " + ant.properties['key.alias'])
}
```

Results of running: gradle test

```
D:\Data\test>gradle test
:test
Value of ants key.alias property: keyaliasvalue

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.787 secs
```

Notes:

1) For my test case I place both the ant build.xml and build.gradle in the same directory.

2) Notice I use the format:

```
ant.properties['key.alias'].
```

If there was not a period (.) in the property name it would be easier. Because the Gradle script is an actually Groovy file, the (.) causes Groovy to think you are trying to access a nested property on an object. Without the (.) in the name, like 'keyalias', you could simplify the syntax to:

```
ant.keyalias
```

Comment: Thank you again! This was very helpful. I'll probably remove the . from my ant properties.. then again the format you used is a little more clear what's going on.